Kibana Map: Enable tooltips for ES|QL layer
I'm trying to display some alarm data on an ElasticSearch Map, but the data is gathered with a ES|QL query:
from my_index_a*,my_index_b*
| where location is not null
| where final_severity != "Cleared"
| sort occurrence_time desc
| limit 10000

The data is displayed correctly on the map (location is a GeoPoint data type), however, the "Show tooltips" option for the layer is grayed out, and there is also no "Tooltip fields" option for the new layer.
Any ideas how I could enable tooltips for this layer type? I'd like the users to be able to click on a location an visualize data.
My Kibana version is 8.13.2
Thanks!
